# Finding the closed form of recurrent sequences

Tags: recurrence-relations

What are the famous (general) methods to find the closed form of a given recurrent sequence?

The only method I know of is the "generating function" method. However it only works in very special cases; the given recurrence should look like (where the recurrent sequence is $U_n$):

$$\sum_{k=0}^m \alpha_k U_{n - k} = W_n$$

Where $(W_n)$ is nice enough.

But what about the cases, say: $f(U_n) =W_n$?

I know there is no general procedure to solve a recurrence which may be of any type, but:

> I would like to know: what are some famous techniques, special cases, famous books, etc. that handle this subject?

Answer (score 1):

Wilf's *generatingfunctionology* is considered to be THE book on [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/DownldGF.html)

You might also want to check out *A=B* by Petkovšek, Wilf, Zeilberger: [https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/%7Ewilf/AeqB.html)

The general case gets VERY messy. Integer partitions are an example where there is a "nice" recurrence, but no "short" formula is known.