# Finding a function $f$, which makes a certain expression constant (second-order linear ordinary differential equation)

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. Is it possible to find a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, such that the expression

$$a\big( f(n+2)-f(n)-1\big)+nb\big(f(n-1)-f(n)\big)+n(n-1)c \big( f(n-2)-f(n)+1\big)$$

does not depend on $n$, i.e. is constant?

I tried to look at the special case $a=b=c=1$ and find

$$\big( f(n+2)-f(n)-1\big)+n\big(f(n-1)-f(n)\big)+n(n-1) \big( f(n-2)-f(n)+1\big)$$

Now, I imagine I could use some sort of logarithmic function like

$$g(n)=\log(n!)$$

which, gives the expression

$$g(n)-g(n-2)=\log(n(n-1))$$

to cancel out $n(n-1)$, but I wasn't able to write down the exact function $f$.

*EDIT:* According to Jean Marie's advice, I tried to write this down using an approach for a generating function

$$A(x):=\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n x^n$$

I am rewriting the equation and set it equal to $0$:

$$a_{n+2}-a_n+n(a_{n-1}-a_n)+n(n-1)(a_{n-2}-a_n+1)=0$$

(Also I remove $-1$, because this won't affect the expression of being constant.)

This can be rewritten as

$$n(n-1)=(n(n-1)+n+1)a_n-a_{n+2}+na_{n-1}-n(n-1)a_{n-2}$$

I get following results:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 0} n(n-1)x^n &= x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2} \sum_{n\ge 0} x^n = \frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}\\
\sum_{n\ge 0} n(n-1)a_nx^n&=x^2\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^n)=x^2A''(x)\\
\sum_{n\ge 0} na_nx^n&=x\sum_{n\ge 0} a_n\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)=xA'(x)\\
\sum_{n\ge 0} a_nx^n&=A(x)\\
\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n+2}x^n&= \frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n+2}x^{n+2}= \frac{1}{x^2} (A(x)-a_0-a_1x)\\
\sum_{n\ge 0} na_{n-1}x^n&= x \sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n-1}\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)
 = x \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n-1}(x^n)\\
&= x \frac{d}{dx} (a_{(-1)}+xA(x))
=xA(x)+x^2A'(x)\\
\sum_{n\ge 0} n(n-1)a_{n-2}x^n&=x^2 \frac{d^2}{dx^2}\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n-2}x^n=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(a_{(-2)}+a_{(-1)}x+x^2A(x))\\
&=x^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(x^2A(x))=2x^2A(x)+4x^3A'(x)+x^4A''(x)
\end{align}$$

Putting all together will give

$$\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}=x^2A''(x)+xA'(x)+A(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}(A(x)-a_0-a_1x)-xA(x)-x^2A'(x)-2x^2A(x)-4x^3A'(x)-x^4A''(x)$$

Suppose $a_0=a_1=0$, we find

$$\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}=x^2A''(x)+xA'(x)+A(x)-\frac{1}{x^2}A(x)-xA(x)-x^2A'(x)-2x^2A(x)-4x^3A'(x)-x^4A''(x)$$

which is a second-order linear ordinary differential equation. Rearranging the coefficients will give the following alternate form:

$$\frac{2x^2}{(1-x)^3}=\big(-\frac{1}{x^2}+1-x-2x^2\big)A(x)+\big(x-x^2-4x^3\big)A'(x)+\big(x^2-x^4\big)A''(x)$$

Unfortunately, I am stuck here again. If anyone can give me a hint how to solve this equation, I would be very thankful!

Any help or hint is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know the technique of generating functions ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I don't precisely know the technique. Can you perhaps recommend any article on it?

Comment: On this site for example, there are a lot of questions that have been solved with generating functions, the main idea here is to figure out that coefficients $n$ and $n(n-1)$ will introduce derivatives of first and second orders.

Comment: See the references given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1400791): both are very good books.

Comment: This looks very interesting, thank you! I will give it a try!